# Add Lists in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, list, distinct

How to add two lists and get the distinct values in SQL?

Example:

```
Id  List1   List2      All_List_Elements
1  [1,2,3]  [1,2,4,5]  [1,2,3,4,5]
```

How can I achieve this in SQL?

Comment: tag the DBMS which u r using.

Comment: Not a table design I'd chose.

Comment: this looks like a problem of de-normalised data

Comment: @Yogesh Sharma tagged DBMS

Comment: As others have said, If possible List1, List2 should be separate tables with each comma separated value as a new row

Comment: yes that can be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #TEMP
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
Id INT
,List1 VARCHAR(100)  
,List2 VARCHAR(100) 
)    

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 1 , '[1,2,3]',  '[1,2,4,5] '

; WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                split.a.value('.', 'varchar(1000)') AS List1 
         FROM  (SELECT id, 
                       Cast('<S>' 
                            + Replace((Replace(Replace(list1, '[', ''), ']', '') 
                            ), 
                            ',', 
                            '</S><S>') 
                            + '</S>' AS XML) AS List1 
                FROM   #temp)AS A 
               CROSS apply list1.nodes('S') AS Split(a)), 
     cte2 
     AS (SELECT id, 
                split.a.value('.', 'varchar(1000)') AS List2 
         FROM  (SELECT id, 
                       Cast('<S>' 
                            + Replace((Replace(Replace(list2, '[', ''), ']', '') 
                            ), 
                            ',', 
                            '</S><S>') 
                            + '</S>' AS XML) AS List2 
                FROM   #temp)AS A 
               CROSS apply list2.nodes('S') AS Split(a)), 
     final 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   cte 
         UNION 
         SELECT * 
         FROM   cte2) 
SELECT '[' + Stuff((SELECT ', ' +list1 FROM final FOR xml path ('')), 1, 2, '')+ ']' AS All_List_Elements
```

Result

```
All_List_Elements
-----------------
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```